# Ignore URL segment and load same page wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a page that uses a custom page template that has a custom permalink like this:

```
https://example.com/warehouse/profile/
```

Now, I want wordpress to accept any requests with a url format as below but still show the same contents as on above page.

```
https://example.com/warehouse/profile/this-is-yet-another-profile-somewhere/
```

Here we should ignore the added segment */this-is-yet-another-profile-somewhere* at the end or URL.

My goal is not to redirect but accept the url with added segment

Answer (score 0):

This should work .
Put the following code at the top of your WordPress htaccess.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(warehouse/profile)/(.+)$ /$1/ [L]
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Yes it ignores the last segment but it's getting removed on the url. I want to know if it's possible to keep that segment on the url

Comment: @RaymondUkit It doesn't remove the URL segment it just maps that URL to the original version. Are you sure the rule is correctly placed at the top?